# ideas on migrating large tfvc repository to git

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

Currently we have our entire code in one large tfvc repository (around 80GB) and we have around 10 build pipelines with that tfvc repository as version control. We have also given workspace mappings. And there are few folders which are common for all the build pipelines.

Now we are planning to migrate from tfvc to git (including history). For this, we opted for git-tfs command.

Which option is better?

- migrating entire large tfvc repository to single git repository? or
- migrating entire large tfvc repository to multiple git repositories?

I tried migrating to single git repository but there is no option for workspace mappings. (at this time we cannot use yaml based pipelines).

I also tried migrating to multiple git repositories. But i need to specify the common folders in all the repositories.

Can someone suggest me the best approach.

Comment: since you had single repository in tfvc migrate to single repository and then creating multiple git repositories out of the single git repository is advised, this will mean minimal changes to your build pipelines and also less disruption for developers. Once everyone is comfortable with git you can create multiple repositories in git.. .....  following links could be useful . 1. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/tfvc.html -   2. https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Kart Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried migrating to single git repository but there is no option for
> workspace mappings.

For this issue , please refer to this [blog](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/biggit-git-for-large-and-tall-tfs-repositories), I think it will help you.

For Large or dispersed repositories:

There are a couple scenarios where this interoperability does not work so nicely. One is if your TFS workspace has a lot of mappings. Both git-tfs and git-tf **can only clone a single TFS server folder**. This is fine if all of your mappings fall under a single root folder that is of a manageable size. However, these multi mapping workspaces often have so many mappings precisely because the root is too large to map on its own.

This blog gives some possible ways on how to deal with this situation.

In this [document](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/README.md) ,it also states "git-tfs is designed to work outside of any existing TFS workspaces."

In addition , here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/mapping-my-tfvc-actions-to-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line) about "map your familiar TFVC commands and workflows to Git" you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your response Hugh Lin. I went through the article and looks very helpful.